# How can I search for questions with <=2 answers?

Tags: support, search

Search help page says that you can search for questions with a **minimum** # of answers:

```
questions that have a minimum number of answers           answers:3 apples
(or no answers)                                           answers:0 apples
```

How can questions with a **maximum** number of answers be searched for? (e.g. with 0, 1 or at most 2 answers)?

Comment: If search doesn't allow it, the data explorer would definitely allow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Just keep going through the pages.

[image]

That's on page 10 of the unanswered tab

Comment: Fearless and inventive...

Answer (score 1):

Data explorer can but the data is only updated monthly.  Search can't.  Maybe you can raise a feature request?

Comment: me (personally) raising a feature request on MSO is one the the most assuredest, dead on certain, 100% certified ways of having the feature forever rejected. Tested in practice. I'm Bad Juju :)